# Why does my media query (max-width) is off by ~30pixels? It applies the css 30 pixels over the max-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I used to have the same problem with my very first website.
I would apply a max-width media query, and it would be off by 40-50pixels, meaning it would apply the css over the max-width restriction.

This is what I mean:
http://postimg.org/image/xg2uboxcz/

Notice how the browser I'm on is at 380 pixels, but it applies the Max-Width Media Query that I put on at 352 pixels.

What's causing this?
I have 100% made sure none of the other media queries are contradicting it, and I have made sure every single media query is closed properly. 
I don't even have a min-width that applies this css. So why is it off?

Comment: is that the browser width of screen width it's showing at 382 ? It might be showing you the total width ( including scrollbars and borders )

Comment: try using `*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}` at the beginning of your stylesheet. This resets the CSS before running your CSS code.

Comment: I used margin0 padding0 on day 1 of creating this website.

Comment: @naughtylus did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.  Thanks.